# The disabled attribute of a dynamically created button in php not changing using it's name or id in jquery but it's css property is changing

Tags: php, jquery

None of the commented statement are working but the uncommented one is working perfectly fine

```
echo "<div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-3 emphasis'>
                    <button class='btn btn-primary btn-block disabled' name = 'proceed' id= 'proceed'><span class='fa fa-user'></span> Proceed </button>
                </div> "  //This is dynamically generated button using php


  $('[name="proceed"').css('background-color','black');
                            // $('[name="proceed"]').removeAttr('disabled');
                            // $('[name="proceed"]').attr('disabled',false);
                            // $('[name="proceed"]').prop("disabled",false);
                            //$('#proceed').prop("disabled",false);
                            //$('#proceed').attr('disabled',false);
                            // $('#proceed').removeAttr('disabled');
```

Comment: And what is your question? You may want to read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to set attribute `disabled` while it's class name

You need either set `disabled` as attribute or use `removeClass` function

```js
 $('[name="proceed"').css('background-color','black');
                            $('[name="proceed"]').removeClass('disabled');
                            // $('[name="proceed"]').attr('disabled',false);
                            // $('[name="proceed"]').prop("disabled",false);
                            //$('#proceed').prop("disabled",false);
                            //$('#proceed').attr('disabled',false);
                            // $('#proceed').removeAttr('disabled');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-3 emphasis'>
                    <button class='btn btn-primary btn-block disabled' name = 'proceed' id= 'proceed'><span class='fa fa-user'></span> Proceed </button>
                </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
$('button[name="proceed"]').css('background-color','black');
```

***EDIT:***

**Disabling input**:

```
$("#proceed").prop('disabled', true);
```

**Enabling Input**:

```
$("#proceed").prop('disabled', false);
```

Comment: the css statement is working fine. The problem is with rest of the commented statements

Comment: I cannot agree with you about the uncommented line because there is a syntax error in your query path expression. If you are curious about how to disable/enable input, here is how:

$("#proceed").prop('disabled', true); // disable

$("#proceed").prop('disabled', false); // enable